# positive matrices with largest entry of each row and column is diagonal entry

Tags: linear-algebra, computational-mathematics, positive-definite

I am interested in matrices with positive entries and the largest entry in each row and column is the diagonal entry. Is there a name for such matrices? How to generate such positive definite matrices?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, they are called [diagonally dominant matrices](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Diagonally_dominant_matrix). I had seen an application of them in a numerical analysis course for Jacobi iteration method. "An Hermitian strictly diagonally dominant matrix with real positive diagonal entries is positive definite" so that can help with creating diagonally dominant matrices that are positive definite. There are more details on the wikipedia page..

Comment: if you re-check the definition, you'll see OP's matrices need not be diagonally dominant

Comment: I see, the positivity of entries and column condition. You're right. What op wants can be formulated in terms of diagonally dominant matrices but it wouldnt be a single name. Apologies. My quotation applies to second question, picking Hermitian matrices with real entries, symmetric, that is strictly diagonaly dominant in terms of rows will be strictly dominant in terms of columns.